# Undefined variable: jobs in laravel

Tags: laravel

***My controller:*** 
function index:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
       //there is error Undefined variable: jobs
         return view('jobs.index')->with('jobs', $jobs);
    }
```

Why

Comment: because you didn't define a variable named `$jobs` ... it is pretty self explanatory

Comment: Because the variable does not exist in this context. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `$jobs` variable in the method.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
   $jobs = // Some code here;

   return view('jobs.index')
      ->with('jobs', $jobs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way to achieve this is by doing something like this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {

         $data['jobs'] = DB::table('your-table')->get();
         return view('jobs.index',$data);
    }
```

with the above code snippet, you could be able to use the variable job in your blade like this:

```
   @foreach($jobs as $j)
      {{ $j->fieldName }}
   @endforeach
```

the above is use when you use get() in your database query. Hope it helps!!!